# a script that terminates all processes owned by the current user,

Tags: linux, bash

I don't know how to write a scrypt that terminates all processes owned by the current user whose machine time (TIME) is greater than 1 minute

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

`killall -u ${USER}` should do the trick.

See [the command documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) and check if your environment is populating USER variable with current user.

Comment: Warning: there are at least two different utilities named `killall` that do significantly different things, so check your OS's documentation (i.e. the man page) to see if this will work with the one you have.